# How do I adjust the fan speed on my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, fan, overheating

I have an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti  graphics card that has a base fan speed of 0 and because of that the GPU hits 50℃ to 60℃. That is too hot. Even when the fans are on minimum, it sits at high to mid 20s.

I've tried [Green With Envy](https://gitlab.com/leinardi/gwe) and the X server settings, but I just this error when I try to set the fan's speed (also see bottom left of the screenshot):

> Failed to set new Fan Speed!

[image: NVIDIA Settings showing error on the bottom left]

I have tried other drivers from the Additional Drivers app built in Ubuntu, but that didn't fix it. I have also tried downloading drivers from NVIDIA's website but it doesn't let me install them. I get this error:

[image: error when trying to install NVIDIA drivers]

I don't know what this means or how to fix it and I have tried restarting my computer and only running terminal, but that did not fix it as well.

Can someone help me fix this? I hate using my computer for long periods of time on Linux because it sits between 50℃ and 60℃.  On Windows it sits at mid 20s.

My Ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS. (I cannot get to the *About* page in Settings because its not there for some reason; I have posted this issue on another question).

Comment: which nvidia driver are you using

Comment: I don't have a solution to your issue, but I just want to let you know that 50-60℃ are not considered a very high temperatures. The reason why you get much lower temperatures on Windows is that on Windows the NVIDIA GPU is used on demand, when needed by your applications, so the integrated GPU is used most of the time, which makes your dedicated GPU work in much lower temperatures. On Ubuntu with X11 on the other hand, currently, the dedicated GPU works constantly, so temperatures are higher. That doesn't mean that temperatures around 50℃ harm your GPU or PC though.